# SSH private key password prompt with no info which application requires it

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, ssh

Today I have migrated to Ubuntu 18.04. Now I am getting constantly asked to enter my private ssh key password every 30 minutes or so. The problem is that the prompt just says `an application` does not specify which application. Anyone aware of a way to detect which app exactly would like to access my private key?

Comment: You could enter a bad password and see which application fails. You could use `xlsclients` from the `x11-utils` package.

Comment: Thank you, but the bad password didn't reveal which application was requesting it. :) I am not able to perform `xlsclients` when I am being asked for the password as the prompt blocks everything.